# Found this amazing app on playstore, but how secure is it?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, security, privacy

Today I came across a [app on play store called RLWatcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redlicense.watcher). It is an amazing app which could come in handy in a lot of situations. It lets the user remotely sense movement, sound or even just the slightest motion of the phone and record audio or video for a specified amount of time. It then sends the recording as a email or uploads it to a ftp server. It is amazing!

But I am concerned about my privacy and this app seems a bit fishy. For one thing, the developer of the app could use this app to spy on the user. It could upload video/audio to a third location. Also for getting the recoded clip as an email, we are to submit our gmail account and password. Will my password be safe? Also it is to be noted that the app crashed a lot.

Does Google offer any protection from possible fraud of this type? Will you trust this app if you were in my place? How do you verify?

Comment: You can trust if the app uses OAuth for authentication.

Comment: @Lucky How do i know if the app uses OAuth?

Comment: There should be an icon telling you to sign in to google or something, when you click that a little popup comes up and looks similar to this http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm2bh.png and you will login with the Google account configured in your phone.

Comment: @Lucky Negative, the app in question doesn't use OAuth, un-installing immediately!

Comment: The developer's [website](http://redlicense.com) doesn't show anything other than a logo of itself. (The website is hosted in *Russian Federation*, if it matters.) App was last updated in 2010. There are some other apps available by the same developer but they're not updated either. I think you should contact the developer for the source code if you want to see the reality. // Otherwise, you'll have to monitor the activities of this app: which URL is it connecting to, etc.

Comment: FYI, the app has been removed from the Play Store, possibly rendering this question moot. If possible, consider editing it to make the situation more generalized without depending on the app. Thanks.